# Elasticsearch filter query does not return any document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I cannot understand why if I query Elasticsearch with filter like this:

```
 curl -H'content-type: application/json' "localhost:9200/.kibana/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "index-pattern"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":4,"successful":4,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

As you can see, I have empty result set.
But instead I do have a document where "type" field equals to "index-pattern".

```
  {
    "_index": ".kibana",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "index-pattern:c37de740-7e94-11eb-b6c2-4302716621be",
    "_score": 0,
    "_source": {
      "index-pattern": {
        "title": "r*",
        "timeFieldName": "@timestamp",
        "fields": "<omitted - too long>"
      },
      "type": "index-pattern",
      "references": [],
      "migrationVersion": {
        "index-pattern": "7.6.0"
      },
      "updated_at": "2021-03-06T15:58:18.062Z"
    }
  }
```

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: I currently don't have access to any local Elasticsearch instance, but what's the type of `type` field? `keyword`, `text`?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas `type` is always a `keyword`, at least in all my kibana instances. @sscarduzio can please double check the mapping? Also, does accessing that ID directly, i.e. `curl localhost:9200/.kibana/_doc/index-pattern:c37de740-7e94-11eb-b6c2-4302716621be` yield anything?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas   from GET /.kibana, I see the mapping. Here is the type field:

      "type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },

Comment: @JoeSorocin, yes the document comes down all rigjt with: curl localhost:9200/.kibana/_doc/index-pattern:c37de740-7e94-11eb-b6c2-4302716621be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `type` field is mapped as `text` by default and you'd like to apply `term` queries on it, the hyphen will prevent the query from matching because `text` is analyzed by [the standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#text-params) which removes hyphens and other special characters upon ingestion. Having said that, the [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) returns documents that contain an **exact** match (special chars included) which caused your original query to not return anything.

So target the [`.keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword-field-type) [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) instead:

```bash
curl -H'content-type: application/json' "localhost:9200/.kibana/_search" -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term.keyword": {
            "type": "index-pattern"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```